Determine probability distribution by expected value
Suppose we have a discrete random variable $X$ taking values in $\mathscr{X}:=\{x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$.  Given some probability distribution $\mathbb{P}$, we have the expected value of $X$ given by
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\mathbb{P}(X=x_j).$$
I'm curious if there's a way to parameterize $\mathbb{P}$ by the expected value.  That is, for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1\leq c\leq x_n$, can we find a probability distribution $\mathbb{P}_c$ such that
$$c=\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\mathbb{P}_c(X=x_j).$$
Obviously, if $c\in\mathscr{X}$, then this is trivially accomplished by an indicator distribution, so to make this more interesting we should impose $\mathbb{P}_c(X=x_j)>0$ for $1\leq j\leq n$.  Furthermore, when $n=2$, this reduces to a nice system of equations
$$p_1+p_2=1,\qquad x_1p_1+x_2p_2=c,$$
which is uniquely solved by
$$p_1=\frac{c-x_2}{x_1-x_2},\qquad p_2=\frac{x_1-c}{x_1-x_2},$$
when $x_1\neq x_2$.  For $n>2$, clearly (non-unique) solutions exist, but I'm curious about the construction.  Can we always find a solution $\mathbb{P}:(x_1,x_2)\to(0,1)^n$ that's continuous?

Any $c$ such that $c \in [x_1 , x_n]$ is achievable as an expected value. The necessary and sufficient condition is for $c$ to lie in the convex hull of $\{ x_1 , \ldots , x_n \}$, which in this case is the interval $[x_1 , x_n]$.
Let us see whether we can make this happen by letting $\mathbb P( X = x_1 ) = a$, $\mathbb P( X = x_n ) = 1-a$, and $\mathbb P( X = x_i ) = 0$ for $i \neq 1,n$.
We aim to satisfy the equality $$ c = a \cdot x_1 + (1-a) \cdot x_n$$ which is equivalent to $$a = \dfrac{x_n - c}{x_n - x_1}.$$
Therefore, for any $c \in [a_1 , a_n]$, we can achieve $c = \mathbb E[X]$ by letting $\mathbb P( X = x_1 ) = \dfrac{x_n - c}{x_n - x_1}$, $\mathbb P( X = x_n ) = \dfrac{c - x_1}{x_n - x_1}$, and $0$ everywhere else.

This doesn't satisfy the requirement that $\mathbb{P}(X=x_j)>0$ for all $j$.  This is essentially a rewording of my $n=2$ case.

Fix a very small $\epsilon>0$, and let $\mathbb{P}(X=x_j)=\epsilon$, $j=2,...,n-1$. Then a small change in $a$ will achieve your goal.
